# d3._3d() is not a function

Tags: angular, d3.js

I am trying to create cuboid using d3-3d for which I have installed d3-3d using `npm`.

I have imported both the libraries as below:

```js
import { _3d } from 'd3-3d';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

And I'm trying to use `_3d` function as below.

```
var origin  = [480, 250], startAngle = Math.PI/8, beta = startAngle;
  // var svg    = d3.select("#networkdesign").selectAll('svg').call(d3.drag().on('drag', dragged).on('start', dragStart).on('end', dragEnd)).append('g');

  var svg   = d3.select("#networkdesign").selectAll('svg');
  var data  = [[{'x':1,'y':1,'z':-1},{'x':-1,'y':1,'z':-1}],[{'x':-1,'y':-1,'z':-1},{'x':1,'y':-1,'z':-1}],[{'x':1,'y':1,'z':-1},{'x':1,'y':-1,'z':-1}],[{'x':-1,'y':1,'z':-1},{'x':-1,'y':-1,'z':-1}],[{'x':1,'y':1,'z':1},{'x':-1,'y':1,'z':1}],[{'x':-1,'y':-1,'z':1},{'x':1,'y':-1,'z':1}],[{'x':1,'y':1,'z':1},{'x':1,'y':-1,'z':1}],[{'x':-1,'y':1,'z':1},{'x':-1,'y':-1,'z':1}],[{'x':-1,'y':1,'z':1},{'x':-1,'y':1,'z':-1},],[{'x':1,'y':1,'z':1},{'x':1,'y':1,'z':-1},],[{'x':-1,'y':-1,'z':1},{'x':-1,'y':-1,'z':-1},],[{'x':1,'y':-1,'z':1},{'x':1,'y':-1,'z':-1},]];
    var mx, mouseX;
    var _3d = d3._3d()
        .scale(50)
        .origin(origin)
        .rotateX(startAngle)
        .rotateY(startAngle)
        .primitiveType('LINES');
```

Getting above error when `d3._3d()` gets called.

Comment: I've imported this module and it seems like there's no function called primitiveTypes in d3-3d module. Did you mean shape()? Also, you didn't paste the error, so I'm not sure what is not working

Comment: Why are you using `d3._d3()` instead of just `_d3()` directly?

Comment: error i am getting is TypeError: d3._3d() is not a function